# Sensor fusion after intrinsic and extrinsic calibration - Autoware

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, vlp16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!  I am runing autoware v1.12 on nvidia jetson agx with jetpack 4.2. Currently am using live sensors VLP-16 lidar and FLIR ADK thermal camera.
I was able to get the intrinsic and extrinsic calibration by following directions at: https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/sensing/autoware_camera_lidar_calibrator.html

However now, I do not know how to overlay data and get fusion.

I run the calibration publisher using the extrinsic yaml file and generic fields that autoware already has in target_frame, camera_frame, camera_info_topic_name etc  and it runs and exits out of the node - is that how it is supposed to be?

I used Pixel-Cloud Fusion node (https://autoware.readthedocs.io/en/feature-documentation_rtd/DevelopersGuide/PackagesAPI/detection/pixel_cloud_fusion.html)  but it keeps on saying waiting for intrinsic file and the target frame does not exist. Am I supposed to do something else also? The Directions ask for "rectified_image" how am i to do that?

Following the steps from https://youtu.be/pfBmfgHf6zg?t=501 at time 8:20, does not allow me to view both lidar and camera data, it only shows one or the other depending on which frame I pick i.e. velodyne or boson-camera, and then the camera feed does not have any overlay data either.

I would really appreciate if you could direct me of the next steps I could take in order to overlay the data of each sensor and get "sensor fusion". I am very new to this, but am trying to learn and properly document.

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343755/sensor-fusion-after-intrinsic-and-extrinsic-calibration---autoware/) by [msaeUF](https://answers.ros.org/users/51019/msaeuf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-02-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@msaeuf The `pixel_cloud_fusion` node is the correct node for this function. You first need to use the `calibration_publisher` package to publish the camera calibration based on the lidar/camera calibration file that you created. Here is an example command to run the `calibration_publisher` using a launch file from `runtime_manager`:

```
roslaunch runtime_manager calibration_publisher.launch camera_frame:=/camera_frame image_topic_src:=/camera/image_raw file:=/path/to/your/lidar_camera_cal.yaml camera_info_topic:=/camera/camera_info
```

In the above command, replace `/camera_frame` with the TF frame that your camera publishes images in, replace `/camera/image_raw` with the topic name of the raw image from your camera, replace `/path/to/your/lidar_camera_cal.yaml` with the full path to your lidar/camera calibration file produced from the `autoware_camera_lidar_calibration` YAML file, and replace `/camera/camera_info` with the topic that you would like the `calibration_publisher` to publish the calibration info on.

Once this is running, you can use the `pixel_cloud_fusion.launch` file to launch both an `image_rectifier` node (which will generate the rectified image topic) and the `pixel_cloud_fusion` node. You'll have to remap the topics in this launch file to the appropriate topics for your camera and calibration.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msaeUF](https://answers.ros.org/users/51019/msaeuf/) on 2020-02-11**:
Thanks alot!!!